# Matrix and Abelian groups question

Tags: matrices, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a Matrix:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $f\colon v\to Av$ be a homomorphism from $Z^2$ to $Z^2$.

> Find a base $(v_1,v_2)$ to $Z^2$ and $2$ integers $k_1$, $k_2$ s.t $(k_1 v_1, k_2 v_2)$ is a base to $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}(f)$.

We tried to find the kernel of $f$ and use the first isomorphism theorem to find it but we're stuck.

Comment: Please use LaTeX for easy reading.

Comment: The kernel is trivial, so that's not helpful. The image is the subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ spanned by $(1,4)$ and $(2,1)$, which is the same as the subgroup spanned by $(1,4)$ and $(0,7)$, which makes the answer clear.

Comment: yes i can see that but what is the base for z^2?

Comment: Try and figure that out for yourself - it's not difficult!

Comment: I still can't see it, would you please help us anyways?

Comment: OK you can take $v_1 = (1,4)$ and $k_1=1$. What about $v_2$ and $k_2$?

Comment: but z^2 isn't a vector space it's the group z*z with +, so it can't be span with (1,4) and (0,7), cause for example if you have the element (1,1)  how can you represent it with this base using only integers?

Comment: That's correct. But so what? You have to find $v_2$ and $k_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $v_1=(1,4)$, $k_1=1$, $v_2=(0,1)$, $k_2=7$.